# List of installed printers in PropertyGrid

Tags: vb.net

In my application I uses PropertyGrid.
Most of values are predefined in Enums so property grid gives me automatically to chose (in sort of combobox) to choose between them.

Among that I have to choose on which printer would application print.
That data can't be stored on Enum since it differs on almost every machine.

Is here a way to get combobox-like listing of installed printers in property grid?
Of course, I know how to create list of strings with installed printer names.

Comment: I do. You have to make a class for a new type like "PrintersList". See here: http://www.encodedna.com/2013/04/show-printers-using-wmi.htm then under desired property you have to use TypeConverter(GetType(PrintersList))... to show printer names like strings. Combo box will appear automatically.

Answer (score 1):

That Example show you how to display all installed printers via ComBobox, You Can Edit it to Display it On the property Grid:

```
Dim InstalledPrinters As String

' Find all printers installed
For Each InstalledPrinters In _
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters
    Me.Combobox1.Items.Add(InstalledPrinters)
Next InstalledPrinters

' Set the combo to the first printer in the list
Me.Combobox1.SelectedIndex = 0
```

Comment: That part I know. How would I edit it to display on PrepertyGrid?